# Parse a string in specific format and store its content for further processing

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string in the format as below. The string on the LHS could be any string and the result on the RHS has values in the {} of varying length and some are separated by delimiters.

I am not able to understand on how to be able to extract the LHS and RHS into two distinct variables.

Input String format:

```
[TEAM DETAILS]={2,TeamName,23,4697}
```

I want to be able to extract the LHS let us say into an array.
For the RHS, I need to process each entry separated by the comma and stored them into an array as well.

I cannot understand on how to do this. It looks simple but I am not able to get a logic out of it.

Comment: `into an array as` - how should the array be named?

Comment: @KamilCuk It can me name any manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script:

```
# input
in="[TEAM DETAILS]={0001/0880,TeamName,0881,0882/3999,8400/8499,4900/4999,6900/6999,9101,9104,5851,5850,5855,7697}"

# get var name
# remove everything after ]=
var="${in%]=*}"
# remove the leading [
var="${var#[}"

# get values
# remove everything before ={
valstr="${in#*={}"
# remove trailing }
valstr="${valstr%'}'}"
# read string as array
IFS=, read -r -a "values" <<<"$valstr"

# output
declare -p var values
```

[will output in repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/EuphoricLonelyPascal):

```
declare -- var="TEAM DETAILS"
declare -a values=([0]="0001/0880" [1]="TeamName" [2]="0881" [3]="0882/3999" [4]="8400/8499" [5]="4900/4999" [6]="6900/6999" [7]="9101" [8]="9104" [9]="5851" [10]="5850" [11]="5855" [12]="7697")
```

Comment: I dont understand what this does ```declare -p var values```. Cant we just print the two array, var and values?

Comment: You can. `declare -p` prints the value of variable in a way they can be sourced later. [declare bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare)

Comment: I am getting some syntax error with the ```valstr="${in#*={}"```. Can you validate it for me? I get error unmatched ".

Comment: I added a link. The line is ok. Could be you are not running bash as your shell, but I think it should work in any shell. The error - `get error unmatched "` suggest to count all the `"` and see if they match.

Comment: I am executing the file as ```./test``` and it gives me the mismatch error. When I use the cmd ```bash test```, it works. Why does it not work when I run it as ```./test``` ?

Comment: Still, could be you are _not_ running bash as your shell. Did you add `#!/bin/bash` on top of your `./test` file? Or maybe there's an error in old bash, like try `valstr="${in#*'={'}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209798/discussion-between-anna-and-kamilcuk).